# Ошибка при запуске проекта Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Запускаю старый проект в консоль сразу выходит сообщение об ошибке
(Messages Gradle Sync)

> Error:Unsupported method: BaseConfig.getApplicationIdSuffix().
>   The version of Gradle you connect to does not support that method.
>   To resolve the problem you can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>   Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other information from the model.

```
02-03 14:26:06.099 2427-5310/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
```

02-03 14:26:06.105 2427-2427/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
02-03 14:26:06.106 2427-2427/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
02-03 14:26:06.106 2427-5309/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
02-03 14:26:07.035 5323-5323/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
02-03 14:26:07.039 5323-5323/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
02-03 14:26:07.095 5323-5323/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
02-03 14:26:07.102 5323-5323/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
02-03 14:26:07.123 5323-5323/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
02-03 14:26:07.123 5323-5323/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
02-03 14:26:07.124 5323-5323/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
02-03 14:26:07.132 5323-5323/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
02-03 14:26:07.137 5323-5323/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: гляньте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44547225/5330439)

Comment: спасибо приложение синранизировалось но при запуске выбивает ошибку